# How can I stop the taskbar from appearing upon notification from an application on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have set my taskbar on Windows to automatically hide. However, whenever an app sends a notification (leading to its icon pulsing orange on the taskbar), the taskbar opens. Is there anyway to modify this behaviour (via regedit, etc.)?

Comment: Hopefully someone else can chime in and prove me wrong, but I don't believe that this is possible.  There is a good [article on the How-To Geek web page](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31779/fixing-when-the-windows-taskbar-refuses-to-auto-hide-correctly/) that explains our options:  *"For the most part, these issues are by design, and are straightforward to solve—either give the app the attention it wants, or configure it to stop asking for your attention."*

Comment: @Run5k I wish it were that simple, my keyboard doesn't have anti-ghosting and for that reason cannot detect the key combination ctrl+win+right (used for switching desktops) so I've created a script so that ctrl+alt+right/left works instead using autohotkey. However for some reason, if I switch between desktops too quickly, the window that was selected on the desktop will start pulsing orange on the taskbar. Going to have to have a look into creating a different AutoHotKey script

Comment: We are always glad to help, but when you have rather unusual circumstances (and requirements that come with them) surrounding your problem, it is prudent to include those caveats within the original question.  Regardless, unfortunately I am afraid that what you asked for simply isn't possible.

Comment: Are you interested in [How to Disable Notifications in Windows 10](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/disable-notifications-windows-10)?

Comment: @harrymc disabling Notifications doesn't fix this. When an app wants your attention I am wondering what the word Microsoft has for it because I don't think its notification its like 'Focus' or something like that. Set an Outlook appointment or I did a [VBA for minimizing Excel](https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/37070-calling-a-macro-upon-minimizing-maximizing/) 
`Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
ElseIf Wn.WindowState = xlMinimized Then
MsgBox "Minimized " & Wn.Caption
End If
End Sub`

Comment: I assume that setting `ForegroundFlashCount` and `ForegroundLockTimeout` to 0, as in the answer below, didn't help?

Comment: @harrymc I tested both set to `0` then restarting Explorer & neither helped. `ForegroundFlashCount` set to `1` or `0` didn't seem to change the flashing, but I my have only waited 10sec. `0` means flash non-stop per a couple websites which is the opposite of what we want. This is a good question that MAY not have a solution. I am SURE Microsoft designed the taskbar to appear on a app focus/notification (not a system tray notification, but maybe they are the same)

Comment: @gregg The word for it is "focus".

Answer (score 2):

While not ideal, you can double tap the Windows key to quickly hide the taskbar without addressing the notification. You'll have to repeat each time you hover over the taskbar until you address the notification. This is on Windows 11 21H2. I do not know if this applies to all Windows versions.

Additionally, Buttery Taskbar can completely hide the taskbar, though it also disables taskbar-focused shortcuts like Win+[number] to launch a pinned app. https://github.com/CrypticButter/ButteryTaskbar

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that can **disable balloon notifications** in Windows 7, but on Windows 10 I don’t know if it is effective.

Go to the registry and browse down the following key

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

Right-click on the right-hand pane, and create a new 32-bit DWORD with the following values:

Name: `EnableBalloonTips`

Value: `0`

Logoff to see the changes.

**Disable flashing icon/application on Taskbar:**

Open registry:

Go to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`

Editing `ForegroundFlashCount`

Replace the value for Value Data with `1`

Editing `ForegroundLockTimeout`

Replace the value for Value Data with `0`

Restart computer

Also check this link for some ideas.

How to Fix the Windows Taskbar When It Refuses to Auto-Hide Correctly

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31779/fixing-when-the-windows-taskbar-refuses-to-auto-hide-correctly/

In the article it advises this MAY not be possible:

> *For apps that notify you by flashing a taskbar button, there may be nothing you can do*

Comment: Balloons aren’t the problem - I tried the other method a while back too but it didn’t seem to be effective. I’ll try it again and see if it works the second time

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all the known remedies that used to work since Windows 7,
no longer work in the current version of Windows.

It is reported that the main workaround, that of setting in
registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
the values of `ForegroundFlashCount` and `ForegroundLockTimeout`
to `0`, may now cause continuing flashing instead of none.

There does not seem to be any known global solution at the moment.

A somewhat awkward workaround might be to move the taskbar icons
to the traybar, where they cannot flash.
A free utility that does this is
[Traymond](https://github.com/fcFn/traymond/).
Another one is
[TrayIt!](https://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/trayit.html).

I remark that there are two reasons a taskbar button will flash:

1. The program attempts to become the foreground window,
   which is more for older programs. The known settings
   might possibly be more successful with those.
   (I have no data on this.)
2. Programs that are newer will explicitly flash the taskbar button.
   There are no Windows settings for this, so one should look
   for application settings.